# insert into a table, where there already is data

Tags: php, mysql

I have an app, where I have to insert data into a mysql database (and that part works fine).

Now I have to insert data into a table, where there already is some data.

The first part, I insert `row 1`, `row2`, `row3` (and the rest is empty)

then I have to insert into `row4`, `row5` and `row6`.

But I just gives me Database Error. Couldn't add post!

this is my insert code:

```
//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");


if (!empty($_POST)) {
//initial query
$query = "INSERT INTO under_etage (lys_u_s, skilt_u_s, door_u_s ) VALUES   (:lys_u_s, :skilt_u_s, :door_u_s ) where etData ='29.04.2014' ";


//Update query
$query_params = array(

    ':lys_u_s' => $_POST['lys_u_s'],
    ':skilt_u_s' => $_POST['skilt_u_s'],
    ':door_u_s' => $_POST['door_u_s']

);

//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add post!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Post Successfully Added!";
echo json_encode($response);

}
```

what am i missing?

I tried UPDATE but I have to update the right line, so I am trying to update where etDate (date) is the same.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

  $lys_u_s = $_POST['lys_u_s'];
 $skilt_u_s = $_POST['skilt_u_s'];
 $door_u_s = $_POST['door_u_s'];
 $etDate = $_POST['etDate'];


$query = "UPDATE under_etage SET lys_u_s = '$lys_u_s', skilt_u_s = '$skilt_u_s',    door_u_s = '$door_u_s' where etDate ='$etDate' ";
```

it is working :)

Comment: Could you post the complete code? And for your requirement, you could first INSERT and then UPDATE.

Comment: there is a : missing before lys_u_s.

Comment: aha omg. that worked.
hmmm thought it would inset into the same line as the 3 first

Comment: you could also use sprintf to replace the query vars... `$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO under_etage (lys_u_s, skilt_u_s, door_u_s ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s )", $_POST['lys_u_s'], $_POST['skilt_u_s'], $_POST['door_u_s']);
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `lys_u_s` to `:lys_u_s` in insert query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO under_etage (lys_u_s, skilt_u_s, door_u_s ) VALUES (:lys_u_s, :skilt_u_s, :door_u_s ) ";
```

I think you need to use update statement

**Edit**

Your update statement looks wrong

```
UPDATE under_etage SET lys_u_s=:lys_u_s, skilt_u_s=:skilt_u_s, door_u_s=:door_u_s where etData ='29.04.2014'
```

Comment: @user3419331 check now

Comment: no same thing, post is added, but nothing happend in the DB, is it ok that the rows are emty, or should the be null?